# Any listeners available for JXMonthView's traversable buttons?

Tags: java, swing, listener, swingx, jdatechooser

Working with JXMonthView, it is possible to set it as "Traversable," which means that left and right arrows appear next to the month name in the header. They allow for the user to select a different month to view, effectively traversing through the calendar year.

I would like to put an event listener on those arrows so that each time they are clicked, the flagged dates will be refreshed. Currently, this only happens when the user clicks on a date in JXMonthView, which changes the current selection, which fires the refresh. Does anyone know how to access those individual traversing buttons and add a listener to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `firstDisplayedDay` property change.

According to the source code, `BasicMonthViewUI.nextMonth()` or `previousMonth()` invokes `monthView.setFirstDisplayedDay` which in turn invokes `firePropertyChange("firstDisplayedDay", oldDate, getFirstDisplayedDay());`.

For example:

```
monthView.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        if ("firstDisplayedDay".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
            System.out.println("updated");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I needed. I had no idea that it would be necessary to go sifting through the source code for `JXMonthView` and trace it to that "firstDisplayedDay" property. You are awesome, @Aqua!